# C-Grammar in Antlr4 raises error `extraneous input 'int'` on `int main()`

Tags: python, antlr4, grammar

(For a better overview I will link my code, so that there is not too much space used unnecessarily)

**Summary:**

I am currently facing a weird issue when using the [Grammar](https://github.com/Luna-Klatzer/Para-C/blob/antlr4-dev/paraccompiler/antlr/g4/ParaC.g4) (partly modified file I made) made for C in Antlr4. It raises errors when encountering type/function definitions, such as `int main()` or `int x`. I am confused why that is though (partly due to my lack of experience or knowledge), since the rules seem to not contain an issue.

Still, when running the Python-generated code, it logs an error saying:

```sh
extraneous input 'int' expecting {'__extension__', '__builtin_va_arg', '__builtin_offsetof', '_Generic', '(', Identifier, Constant, StringLiteral}
```

Debugging the code I found that the entire declaration is classified as a `primaryExpression`, even though it should be an `assignmentExpression`. So it seems there might be an issue inside the grammar file causing it to identify it incorrectly, or my [implementation](https://github.com/Luna-Klatzer/Para-C/blob/antlr4-dev/paraccompiler/antlr/implem/out/__init__.py) (my file utilising the generated code) contains a weird bug causing this to happen.

If anyone has a clue what it might be or what I could try to fix the issue, I would greatly appreciate that ^^

**Edit: Additional Info**

Here the base version: [link](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4). The changes in my version are minimal and I only added a new type and specifier, meaning it should not interfere with the lexing and correctly identifying it. (Changes can be viewed here: [link](https://www.diffchecker.com/QGaRZ4nV))

Comment: Which rule are you invoking and on which input? Does your input file contain anything before `int main`? Also please post a [MCVE] of your grammar as well as the code that invokes it inside your question instead of as a link. And, assuming that "partly modified" means that you started with an existing grammar and then modified it, please highlight the parts that you've changed and mention which grammar you used as the starting point.

Comment: You are calling to recognize a primaryExpression, not an assignmentExpression. https://github.com/Luna-Klatzer/Para-C/blob/antlr4-dev/paraccompiler/antlr/implem/out/__init__.py#L105

Comment: @kaby76 I realised that later on and learned that the entry rule is in fact not primaryExpression, meaning that my implementation does not make sense in the case. I fixed it now and the errors are gone, so it was now a mistake from my side misunderstanding the grammar. I now use compilationUnit, which solves the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue and it was based on my misunderstanding from how antlr4 dealt with this and how the grammar file was structured. (I realised that after reading @sepp2k comment).

I called the wrong rule, which in this case was `primaryExpression`. This rule was not the actual entry rule, meaning that calling it causes Antlr4 to only call one of the rules needed and therefore parse the entire string wrongly and not recognise anything. I fixed the issue and found that `compilationUnit` was the actual entry, meaning that now everything is parsed fine.

(Also I realised that my question was rather loosely formed and didn't contain enough information, so sorry about that, but luckily I found the issue rather quickly after realising what was actually going on)